# Removing Browser Tool bar from next page after Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jsp, dom

I have a form like this -

```
<form method='post' name='FormName' action="next.jsp">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="language" value="en">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="country" value="US">
</form>
```

I am submitting the form using -

```
<script language="JavaScript">     
  document.FormName.submit();
</script>
```

I want to disable the browser toolbars from the next page (next.jsp) without modifying the code of next.jsp.

How can I do it?

Comment: create an app with a browser embedded in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Scripts can only try to modify the browser interface of scripted popup windows.